# Angular route fragment should not trigger a wildcard redirect

Tags: angular

If I have routes:

```
[
{ path: "player/:id", component: PlayerComponent, canActivate: [MyAuthGuard], data: { Admin: [MyAuthGuard.IsAdmin] } },
{ path: "setup", pathMatch: "full", component: SetupComponent, canActivate: [MyAuthGuard], data: { Admin: [MyAuthGuard.IsAdmin] } ),
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "setup"}
], { useHash: false }
```

And a fragment activated by a button tag like this:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/player']" fragment="info">INFO</button>
```

And fragment subscription code like so:

```
export class PlayerComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy {

routeFragmentSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.routeFragmentSubscription = this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
        if (fragment) {
            let element = document.getElementById(fragment);
            if (element) {
                element.scrollIntoView();
            }
        }
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeFragmentSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
}
```

Then, while at the route "player/112" I click that button and the route "player/112#info" triggers the wildcard and redirects to "setup#info".

Expected behavior

With the above setup, I should be able to click the button and have the route remain "player/112#info" and have the page scroll to the id of the fragment in the DOM.

Comment: Angular version: 
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

Comment: using browser Chrome (desktop) version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v6.2.2
- Platform:  Windows 10

Comment: also reported it in 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19708

Comment: [routerLink]="['/']" isn't this mean you are going to you localhost/#router which leads to the wildcard ?

Comment: I want to be able to use both the route parameter for the playerID and the has for the fragment when I do /player/112#info but I don't think that Angular in prepared for this scenario.

Comment: I edited the question to /player instead of just / but the problem is not there.

Comment: I use  this.router.navigate(['../order', '123'], { relativeTo: this.route, fragment: 'rowId'}); and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the ID in the routerLink to match the route.
INFO